Java Apache PDFBox Fill PDF Fields (Errors)
I am getting errors while attempting to fill out many fields in multiple PDFs. The code is actually creating and filling the PDFs as expected, and saving the PDFs, however the code is throwing errors. I am trying to understand what is causing these errors.
Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths

ERROR FlateFilter FlateFilter: stop reading corrupt stream due to a DataFormatException

ERROR COSParser object stream 51 could not be parsed due to an exception

This is the code I use:
for (int dCounter = 4; dCounter < nColCount; dCounter++) {
    File adobeFile = new File(strDestFileName);

    PDDocument adobeDocument = Loader.loadPDF(adobeFile);
    PDDocumentCatalog adobeCatalog = adobeDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm adobeAcroForm = adobeCatalog.getAcroForm();
    PDField adobeField = adobeAcroForm.getField(strArrayHeaders[dCounter]);

    if(!Objects.equals(strArrayCellValues[dCounter], "")) {
        adobeField.setValue(strArrayCellValues[dCounter]);
    }
    FileOutputStream adobeOut = new FileOutputStream(adobeFile);
    adobeDocument.saveIncremental(adobeOut);

    adobeDocument.close();
}


I noticed 3 other things: 1) You're opening the file for every field instead of only once; 2) You're using saveIncremental() in a way that may not work at all. Please take the time to read its javadoc. 3) You're saving to the input file instead of saving to a different file, this can destroy the input file because of the parse on demand behavior in 3.0.

Save as new temp file so you can compare / check, ideally once not per field. Only overwrite an input file if you're certain it worked and by using move/replace temp -> original name and after all documents are closed. Never while you have FileInputStream open to same one.

Appreciate all the feedback. I was tired when I originally wrote this and was making fundamental file io no nos.  This is what works:
File adobeFile = new File(strSourceFileName);
PDDocument adobeDocument = Loader.loadPDF(adobeFile);
PDDocumentCatalog adobeCatalog = adobeDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm adobeAcroForm = adobeCatalog.getAcroForm();

for (int dCounter = 4; dCounter < nColCount; dCounter++) {

PDField adobeField = adobeAcroForm.getField(strArrayHeaders[dCounter]);

if(!Objects.equals(strArrayCellValues[dCounter], "")) {
    adobeField.setValue(strArrayCellValues[dCounter]);
    }
}

File adobeDestFile = new File(strDestFileName);
FileOutputStream adobeOut = new FileOutputStream(adobeDestFile);
adobeDocument.saveIncremental(adobeOut);
adobeDocument.close();
adobeOut.close();


Because you're still using saveIncremental without marking the widgets as updated, it isn't sure whether the changes will be seen. I'm surprised that it works at all.
